# How to search a string or character which is in [[String]] type

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchresultscontroller

```
//Am not getting any search list of cells
//when am searching am getting empty array every time.

var actors = [["a0","b0","c0","d0"],["a1","b1","c1","d1"],["a2","b2","c2","d2"],["a3","b3","c3","d3"]]

var filterArr:[[String]] = []

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {        
    print("Searching for text:----\(searchController.searchBar.text!)")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF Contains[c] %@" , searchController.searchBar.text!)

    filterArr = (actors as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate) as! [[String]]
    print(filterArr)

}
```

Comment: Do you expect an array as a return value?

Comment: yes array of index 0 , index 1  and so on.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Objective-C stuff like `NSPredicate` and `NSArray` when you don't have to. Use Swift's `filter` and `map`.

From what you described in the comments, you want to keep only the inner arrays that contains the searched text. You can do this:

```
filterArr = actors.filter { $0.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) }
```

If you want to keep only the inner arrays that contains items that *contains* the search text, do this:

```
filterArr = actors.filter { $0.contains { $0.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!) } }
```

Comment: This is working fine but if i search for 'a0' only a0 value is available in the array and same is displaying in the cell.

Comment: This is working fine but if i search for 'a0' only a0 value is available in the array and same is displaying in the cell. actually my table view cell contains ->["a0","b0","c0","d0"] in one cell and this array data ->["a1","b1","c1","d1"] is in another cell.. Here what am trying to do is if i search for 'a0'  i want all the values of  "a0","b0","c0","d0" and similarly if i search for 'c0'  i want all the values ->  "a0","b0","c0","d0". and few arrays has info like ->[[a0","b0","c0","d0],[a1","b1","c0","d0]]i don't know whether is it possible or not. if it is possible please help me. thank you